# ASP.NET MVC 3 and Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm incorporating google map into an app I am building. When the app loads, it displays a list of locations from an Sql server database on the map canvas. However, there is also a requirement that the app should be able to display a location(s) on the map as user types in a location name in a textbox provided and when the textbox is cleared the entire locations should then be redisplayed on the map.The search is to be performed using ajax.

I have a created a controller to do the search but what I am not sure of is how to make the ajax call and display the returned location on the map using javascript.

Any clues or helpful pointers would be very helpful.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and C# for back-end dev.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's `$.ajax`?

Comment: I am familiar with jQuery's `$.ajax` I am more concerned about how to get the value in the textbox `onKeyPress` event and perform the search with the value

Comment: Ah, that's a nasty one. I would recommend a third party library for that, otherwise you'll get a real headache when trying to make is browser compatible. `knockout` for example, has a special binder for this sort of things (valueUpdate). I would recommend the tutorials. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

I've written an app as a proof of concept for this  two weeks ago. You can do this without ajax or Knockout in plain javascript. A little knowledge of Google Maps, arrays, and optionally map and filter is all you need.

This will work for up to a few hundred markers. If you need to deal with thousands you'll have to make it dynamic, but you can use the techniques in this answer to achieve that as well. The only difference is that instead of a static array (`data`) that you drop on the page on rendering, you retrieve the array using ajax and can do the filtering serverside, optionally. Depends on the size of the potential answer you receive.

```
<script>
    var map,
        markers = [],
        data = [
            {
                id: 1,
                plaats: "Nieuwe Markt 100 Gouda",
                geo: "52.0130174,4.7110039"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                plaats: "Herpstraat 3 Gouda",
                geo: "52.0138912,4.7082084"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                plaats: "Van Bergen IJzendoornpark 7 Gouda",
                geo: "52.0141417,4.7002510"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                plaats: "Snoystraat 4 Gouda",
                geo: "52.0090531,4.7015962"
            }
        ];

    // Initialise Google Map
    function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {});
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        // User types something in filter textbox
        document.getElementById('filtertextbox').onkeyup = (function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var filtervalue = document.getElementById('filtertextbox').value;

                // Anything to filter?
                if (filtervalue.length == 0) {
                    // Show all markers
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        markers[i].setMap(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Hide all markers
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        markers[i].setMap(null);
                    }
                    // Filter data array
                    data.map(function (b) {
                        if (b.plaats.toLowerCase().includes(filtervalue.toLowerCase())) {
                            // Show this marker
                            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                                if (markers[i].id == b.id) {
                                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0);
        });

        // Adds a marker to the map
        // Uses the DROP animation to drop them one after the other
        function createMarker(dataitem, timeout) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var l = dataitem.geo.split(',');
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(l[0]), parseFloat(l[1]));
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    id: dataitem.id
                });
                markers.push(marker);
            }, timeout);
        }

        // Limit the visible area to just the markers that we have
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var l = data[i].geo.split(',');
            bounds.extend(new google.maps.)
            bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(l[0]), parseFloat(l[1])));
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        // Drop the markers onto the map
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            createMarker(data[i], i * 100);
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR API KEY]&callback=initMap" async defer>
```

Let's walk through the code:

Create an javascript array of places that you want to make available and drop this on the page in a variable. (You can use one of the JSON serializers for this). You don't seem to want to make a dynamic page so can work with a static result set. The items in the array should either include the len/lat or the address, depending on how you place them on the map (Google Maps supports only those two methods) and any optional data you want to be able to filter on.

Create an empty array to hold your Google Map holders; loop through the array and create the google.map.marker objects (this will automatically display them on the map), put these objects in the array so you can do stuff with them at a later point.

For your filter textbox, create a keypress event. Inside the event put a  `setTimeOut(function(){ ... },0)` function (to make sure you have the actual content of the textbox when you retrieve from the element), create a foreach loop over the array of stored markers and if the property of your choice contains (use `String.prototype.includes()`) what is being typed, make that marker visible (either set the `.map` property to the map, or use `marker.setVisible(true)`. You start the event with hiding all markers. If the textbox is empty, make everything visible.

As bonus, you can limit the map to only display the area where your markers are located with `fitBounds`. You could add a click event to the marker and do something when a user clicks the marker. :)